# Using p5.js with F# Fable

Tags: f#, p5.js, fable-f#

I'm trying to create an web page with F# Fable and p5.js. I have the `setup` and `draw` functions correctly declared, and p5.js is referenced in the HTML. However nothing seem to work: The `setup` function is never called and thus `canvas` is never created. No error message is displayed.

The following is the code I'm using.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    canvas {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    div {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>

  <title>Simple Fable App</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fable.ico" />
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.Import

[<Emit("fill($0)")>]
let fill (_: int): unit = jsNative

[<Emit("rect($0, $1, $2, $3)")>]
let rect (_: int) (_: int) (_: int) (_: int): unit = jsNative

[<Emit("frameRate($0)")>]
let frameRate (_: int): unit = jsNative

[<Emit("createCanvas($0, $1)")>]
let createCanvas (_: int) (_: int): unit = jsNative

let setup () =
    createCanvas 500 500
    frameRate 15

let draw () =
    fill 255
    rect 10 10 100 101
```

---

If I use the very same HTML above with the equivalent JS it will work as expected, so I assume Fable is messing up my somewhere.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    canvas {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    div {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>

  <title>Simple Fable App</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fable.ico" />
</head>
<body>

</body>

<script>
function setup () {
    createCanvas(500, 500)
    frameRate(15)
}

function draw () {
    fill(255)
    rect(10, 10, 100, 101)
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The `setup` and `draw` functions are compiled within a module, not globally as you declare them in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the hint given by @FyodorSoikin, I searched the documentation and found out [how to add properties to JS objects](http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#dynamic-typing).

So I added the two relevant functions to the `Browser.window` object (i.e. made them global):

```
Browser.window?setup <- setup
Browser.window?draw <- draw
```

And now everything works.